# integrating meteor with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meteor

Our team has a very large RoR app in production already, but we're looking for a new workflow for the future.  Since our team is made of mostly Rails devs and me (JavaScript), I've been looking into the idea of connection a Meteor app to a Rails API for the backend.  I'm not too familiar with Meteor yet so I'm wondering if this is possible as of 0.6.5?  Or if any Meteor devs see this, will it be possible in the current road map?

My current thoughts are to create collections using data from the Rails API and update the Rails records when the meteor collections are changed, so theoretically both databases will be updated while taking advantage of Meteor's client-side features.  As I've said, I'm not too familiar with the specifics of Meteor yet so this may not work like I'm thinking.

Or maybe I can't use collections at all and have to manually create a minimongo using the API data and manually send back as it's updated?

This also brings the question of publishing and subscribing to the collections, which I'm not sure how that would work either.

Any help or enlightenment is appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any luck here? I've been considering something similar.

Comment: Not much. I'm waiting on further development of Meteor to try this out, but you might want to check out https://github.com/frozeman/MeteorFrontend , but you still need to create your own DDP client/server for full reactivity.  You might have more luck using emberJS with Rails as there's https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails. But if you're like me, you really like Meteor and want to use it. It sounds possible but I don't have the time to implement it.  Hopefully it'll be easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a DDP client gem that supports DDP 1.0. It's not finished yet, but the most common functionality already works: https://github.com/clemenshelm/metybur

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DDP (the live communication protocol meteor uses) client such as https://github.com/tmeasday/ruby-ddp-client. It doesn't look like its been maintained in a while but the changes are trivial to bring it up to [spec](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md). When it was written the DDP protocol wasn't official.

So you can connect to Meteor with DDP and do everything you could do pretty much with [DDP.connect](http://docs.meteor.com/#ddp_connect) in the docs.

Comment: I was actually looking into that but I don't have any experience with DDP and very little with Meteor so it might take me a while to figure the whole process out.  It looks like it may be possible with https://github.com/eddflrs/meteor-ddp .  So would this go on the Rails App and subscribe/watch for changes on collections in the meteor app and respond accordingly?